# Weird errors when deploy play

Tags: deployment, playframework

Has anyone meet the following issue?

```
The file {module:secure}/app/controllers/PaxHeader/Secure.java could 
not be compiled. Error raised is : Syntax error on tokens, delete 
these tokens
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the `Secure` class found in the /app/controllers/PaxHeader in an IDE, does it compile?

What if you run `play auto-test`?  does it also fail due to compilation errors?

What if you re-download the Play framework (and adjust your PATH environment variable to point to that new Play Framework distribution) and try again?